# Getting the differences between two IFiles in an eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, diff

I am writing an eclipse plugin that notices when a file has moved or been renamed. In eclipse, this can happen when you choose to move or rename a file. The interesting thing is that in a rename, for example, eclipse will delete the old file and create a brand new file.

I do have access to the old file and the new one:

```
//grab each new and deleted file
IFile oldFile = resourceParser.getDeletedFiles().get(i);
IFile newFile = resourceParser.getNewFiles().get(i);
```

The problem is that in some situations (renaming a package, for example) a file will be moved and the contents of the file will be changed to account for the new package name.

So, I need to get a list of differences between the two files. Like I said, I have access to the two IFiles (the deleted one and the new one) but I want to see how their contents differ. Is there some kind of java diff tool that will produce a simple list of changes that I can manipulate?

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse `org.eclipse.compare` provides a general mechanism for writing diff tools and editors, this is described in the [Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fcompare.htm).

The Java Development Tools part of Eclipse extends this compare support for Java, however the code is in the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.internal.ui.compare` package which is **internal** and consequently not part of the Eclipse API and should not be used [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)

Comment: Great, thanks again! Do you have any suggestions for implementing the diff? I am looking at RangeDifferencer and IRangeComparator, is that how you would do it? Do you happen to know of any examples that I can look at?

Comment: You could look at `org.eclipse.compare.contentmergeviewer.TextMergeViewer`